# Reset 3 Slicers to Select All when in a 4th slicer 'Yes' or 'No' selected

Tags: powerbi

I'm pretty new to PBi and seem to have an opportunity that I can't find a solution for.
I have 4 slicers for 4 flags (a Yes or No value) to display whether a patient has *Condition 1*, *Condition 2* etc. As these 4 conditions aren't mutally exclusive, a patient could have 2 or more conditions, how can I reset 3 slicers to Select All when a 'Yes' or 'No' is selected in a 4th slicer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply - you cannot.

What you can do is a little bit of a hack and consists of using bookmarks and the Bookmark Navigator.

1. Show `Bookmarks` pane and `Selection` pane from the `View` tab in the ribbon.
2. For slicers 1,2 & 3 unselect everything. For slicer 4, select "Yes". Then in the `Selection` pane, select slicer 4 and click the eye icon to hide it.
3. Now select all four slicers in the `Selection` pane, then in the `Bookmarks` pane, click `Add`.
4. Right-click on `Bookmark 3` and select `Data`, `Display`, & `Selected visuals`, and unselect `Current page`.
5. Right-click again, and select `Update`. And again and `Rename` to "Yes".
6. In the `Selection` pane, unhide slicer 4 (clicking on the eye icon). And now select "No" in the slicer. And then, again, hide slicer 4.
7. Repeat steps 3 to 5, to create your "No" bookmark.
8. Now insert the Bookmark Navigator via `Insert` tab in the ribbon, `Buttons` > `Navigator` > `Bookmark navigator`.

Give it a test.

Lastly, you could update slicer 1, 2 & 3 to look like the Bookmark Navigator by going to the Slicer format properties > `Slicer settings` > `Options` and change the Style to `Tile`.